# F5 and pinning content

Tags: performance, f5

We are using an F5 web accelerator.

Does anyone have a walkthrough or reference on how to perform the pinning of CSS, JS and images files in the F5?

Comment: We are using the F5 appliance in front of our 4 WFE's, and using the OOB SharePoint acceleration profile. I think we can do even more than this profile allows by tuning the pinning of certain page elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a walkthrough or anything, but it's pretty simple.  On the load balancer (if your device supports this capability), go to the F5 configuration management page, you can specify what types of files that you want the F5 to cache and for how long.  For example, you might want to apply this setting:

"*layouts/1033/*.js"

This will cache all files with the .js extension so that when a request comes into the F5 for a particular file, it will host it up from the hardware device without making a trip to the SharePoint WFE.  You will need to experiment with the caching times for each item that you decide to cache based on your business needs.

-Rob